# Converting Tuple to Hex with unknown type

Tags: python

The title is a little misleading. Basically, I have a whole bunch of numbers in a huge list of with several different formats. I am passed the value and the type it is in, and expected to unpack them and convert them to HEX-strings.

My latest attempt is :

```
realVal = '0x%08x' %  struct.unpack( evalType, ( rawVal ) )
```

Where realVal is supposed to be a Hex number that is the *real* value of the number, and is used later in my code. evalType is the code letter type of number rawVal is, and rawVal is the raw value ripped straight from a binary file. evalType is recieved by looking in a dictionary. But when the value is a float, it breaks, however in the first 100K cases I run where the value is an integer it is fine.

So I tried to convert the values into integers first by doing:

```
realVal = '0x%08x' %  int ( struct.unpack( evalType, ( rawVal ) ) )
```

But that doesn't work because apparently struct.unpack( evalType, ( rawVal ) ) is a touple, according to the error message.

Also, I found that converting from float to hex can be done by float.hex() so I add in an if statement and I try:

```
realVal = struct.unpack( evalType, ( rawVal ) ).hex()
```

when I know the value is a float, it breaks and says that touples don't have a .hex() function.

So now that I know I am working with a touple, I wonder why it works just fine when the value inside is an integer and why it crashes when it is a float, and how to fix it.

Comment: Some example inputs and example outputs would be useful...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out.

`realVal = struct.unpack( "<" + evalType, ( rawVal ) )[0].hex()`

because it is a touple, and the first index is where my number is stored.

Comment: Slightly more flexible (and handier if you had multiple values you wanted to work with in the unpack - or items that don't support .`hex` but you'd like to represent them as hex): `'{0:08x}'.format(...)`

Answer (score 1):

Usually struct.unpack(..) returns a tuple even if it returns only one element it is returned in the form (x,). So you should try putting a zero index like this: struct.unpack(..)[0].